# Computing the correlation between two Brownian motions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis

Say I have two Brownian motion processes $B=\left\{B_t:t\ge 0\right\}$ and $W=\left\{W_t:t\ge 0\right\}$, with means $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ and variances $\sigma_1^2$ and $\sigma_2^2$, respectively. Also, say that they both have random initial distributions $B(0)$ and $W(0)$.

I want to compute the **correlation**, $\rho$, between $B$ and $W$. I know this is probably very basic, but I have not been able to find a nice formula or expression to be able to compute $\rho$. (Nor do I know it's definition in the case for random processes.) Answers to these questions would be appreciated!

Comment: How is it possible to find correlation without any knowledge on their dependence?

Comment: @NCh maybe my question is not clear. For two random variables $X$ and $Y$, the covariance has a precise definition: $Cov(X,Y) := E[(X-E[X])\cdot (Y-E[Y])]$. Is there a similar definition/formula in the case of random processes?

Comment: https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter10/10_1_3_multiple_random_processes.php